# Invalid namespace in Razor view

Tags: iis, razor, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-mvc-5

I had everything working well. But then I decided to move one type `DateTimeRange` to separate project (DLL in the same solution). Also I changed namespace from `XYZ.ABC` to `XYZ.DEF`.

It works fine in Visual Studio, but after I published site on `IIS`, it throws exception.

```
System.Web.HttpCompileException (0x80004005)
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\...\App_Web__viewName.cshtml.a05ae3fa.cybothwk.0.cs(31):
error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'DateTimeRange' does not exist in the namespace 'XYZ.ABC' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

It says it cannot find `DateTimeRange` in namespace `XYZ.ABC`. But I have updated the view to use model from updated namespace.

I tried to clear ASP.NET temporary files, but it didn't help.
I have references to 2nd project with `copy local` set to true.

Answer (score 1):

1)The first thing you need to check was if the class library's reference in the ASP.NET MVC project had the "Copy Local" property set to true.

2)add the namespace that it couldn't find manually inside the  tag in the web.config file under Views folder (not root folder web.config file):

```
<namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
    ...
  </namespaces>
```

3)tried to add namespace directly to the view itself that is causing the problem. add the @using directive at the beginning of the view:

```
@using MyCustomClass;
```

4)need to check the properties of a class project:

- open project in visual studio.
- right-click on the project name and click on properties.
- Under the Application tab, the "Output type" had selected "Class Library"
  [image]

Comment: I tried everything what you said (found the same answers on Internet), but it didn't work. Anyway I did workaround - changed view name to different, updated controllers, and for now it will be enough...

Comment: It is a workaround, and problem will come back to me. I am still thinking about it, and I'll add an answer when I find correct solution.